# Force user to change password at next logon with Puppet

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

Can someone explain to me how you would force a user to change their password upon first login using Puppet and hiera/yaml?
Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe the user resource caters for such a thing...

Comment: I'm having to look for a certain value in /etc/shadow, once I find that particular value, I want to 'chage' it. At the moment i'm using the following but it doesn't seem to work - possibly down to the way i'm declaring the egrep with the encrypted value containing special characters:

case $::osfamily {
            RedHat: {$action = "chage -d 0 $id"}
    }
 
    exec { "$action":
            path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin",
            onlyif => "egrep -q  -e '$id:<encrypted value>:' /etc/shadow",",
            require => User[$id]
    }

I'd appreciate any thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to declare a new `exec` resource with a command similar to the following:

```
passwd -e LOGIN
```

`passwd -e` expires the current password for the given LOGIN, so the user will be asked to change it during the next login.

Comment: How would I do this if I was using hiera lookups, i.e. as part of a yaml file?
I'd be most grateful for an example.